# MySQL's Group_Concat function miss the nulls. How can group the rows including NULLs.

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Consider the following example of Table1

```
usrID orderID deliverID
1     303     102
1     304     103
2     305     NULL
2     306     105
3     307     NULL
3     308     NULL
```

I want to concat the orderID, deliverID and group as usrID, as following

```
usrID orderID_group deliverID_group
1     303,304       102,103
2     305,306       NULL,105
3     307,308       NULL,NULL
```

I am using the following MySQL query which miss the NULL value.

```
SELECT usrID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(orderID SEPARATOR “,” ) AS orderID_group,
       GROUP_CONCAT(deliverID SEPARATOR “,”) AS deliverID_group
FROM   table1
GROUP  BY usrID;
```

I want to include both NOT NULL and NULL in sequence order. I would appreciate if anyone kindly write the MySQL query. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT usrID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(case when orderID is null then 'null' else orderID end order by orderID) AS orderID_group, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(case when deliverID is null then 'null' else deliverID end order by orderID) AS deliverID_group 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY usrID;
```

Comment: You can add `ORDER BY orderID`, inside (both) group_concat function calls.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works fine inside the MySQL command prompt. But when I am running the query on linux shell command prompt it is not working.

Comment: I am using following command on linux prompt mysql -u -p database -e 'query;'

Comment: @FIROZ: Use `"query"` instead of `'query'`

Comment: @Juergen: Thanks, using "query" i am getting error. only 'query' can give result. I also used system command as: `echo 'query' mysql -u -p database >/path/file.txt. But the result does not contain NULL.